# how to read FoxPro Startup File data file (File Extension .FPM)

Tags: c#, java, etl, foxpro, talend

I got three files to get the data from, but i am not able to get what kind of file is it.

The files are named with - TCPMLD.FPC, TCPMLD.FPK, TCPMLD.fpm.

is there any clue where i can read this file using Talend or other ETL tool or c# or Java language?

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering why I hadn't come across those file extensions in over 15 years working with FoxPro from DOS up to VFP9, and it's because they were only used by the short-lived Foxpro For Macintosh.

If it was me I would either subscribe to the FoxPro mailing list at leafe.com, because a lot of the old-time Fox people are there, or see if you can find the disk images for FoxPro Macintosh and run them up in a Mac emulator.

Comment: i am not sure these are the fox pro files, i googlit and found on post gave me the description about these files. so is there any way to export these file in ASCII format files? even i can use the macintosh

Comment: The .FPM, if it is from FoxPro Mac, will just be a list of commands you can open with a text editor.

Comment: I've been working with this stuff since FoxBase in 1988 and not seen these extensions either, so you're in good company, Alan B :-).  I wonder if those files could simply be DBF/FPT/NDX format, similar to how a .VCX is a DBF and a .VCT is really a .FPT.